# Another div is cut into half when image trying to text on image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I require some help about a problem I have encountered.I was   trying to put text on image using for my webpage. But, whenever I put the position of the image to relative. The div above my image gets cut into half.I would like to note that the div which gets cut in half is set to position:fixed. I have done this so that the div can stay on the page even if I scroll down. Now how do I get text on the image , without cutting my div into half.

Here is my HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Popper JS -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Actor' rel='stylesheet'>
        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid" style="font-family: Actor">
            <div class="row"  style="position: fixed; box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19); background-color: #FFFFFF; padding: 4px;">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                     <img src="images/1-OrderUp!!.jpg" alt="OrderUp logo">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <p class="text-style-1">OrderUp!!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1" style="height: 100px; background: #511F18; width: 2px; margin-left: 784px;"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">`enter code here`
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" style="width: 100px">Log in
                        <?php

                        ?>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1" style="height: 100px; background: #511F18; width: 2px;"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Sign Up
                        <?php

                        ?>
                    </button>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-1" style="height: 100px; background: #511F18; width: 2px;"></div>
            </div><br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12" style="box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19); ">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/home-1.jpg">
                        <h2>Welcome to OrderUp!!</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is what my CSS looks like:

```
.btn.btn-danger.btn-lg{
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 100px;
}
.text-style-1{
    font-family:Actor;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:55px; 
    padding-top:2px; 
    padding-left:20px;  
    color: #511F18";
}
```

This is what my page looks like normally:
[image]
If I change my CSS file like this:

```
.btn.btn-danger.btn-lg{
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 100px;
}
.text-style-1{
    font-family:Actor;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:55px; 
    padding-top:2px; 
    padding-left:20px;  
    color: #511F18";
}
.image { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 200px; 
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
}
```

It looks like this:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add to your text css

```css
h4 {
  position:absloute; /* instead of fixed */
  z-index:999;
  opacity:1;
}
```

you can move it by adding margin top and left thanks.